# Initiate a phone call and return to app afterwards - Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

In my Xamarin application, after user clicks some button I want to make a phone call and then return to my app (ideally to the same place in the code).

Something like this:

```
async Task button_click()
{
     string s = "200-345-6789";
     // await Device.OpenUri("tel:" + s); // can't await this
     ShowAlert("The number " + s + " was called");
}
```

Originally I tried Device.OpenUri, but it's not awaitable.

On Android, StartActivityWithResult worked well for me. I define TaskCompletionSource, start activity with an intent of ActionCall, and inside OnActivityResult function I flag my task as completed, which returns the flow back to the original function.

But on iOS, I can't find anything similar. What would you suggest?

Comment: Just wrap your shared application openURL in an awaited task run anonymous function.

Comment: @SushiHangover - I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. Do you have any example? Do you mean that OpenUri with tel: will end the Task run after the call is finished?

Comment: Check out the messaging plugin: https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins for cross platform goodness of phone calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with this for some more hours, I found the solution - so I thought I'd post it for others to benefit.
What I did is simulation of something similar to Android's `OnActivityResult`.
Inside my `AppDelegate` class I define an event which is fired from its `OnActivated` function. 
Now, inside my function I subscribe to this event passing to the delegate a `TaskCompletionSource` which I define. Then I call `Device.OpenUri("tel:" + phoneNum)`. The phone call is made, and after it ends the user is returned to my app, `AppDelegate.OnActivated` fires my event, my delegate is called and I can mark my task as completed by calling `SetResult`. This makes possible to `await` this function.

Comment: On iOS 10.3 and above, there will be two `OnActivated` calls before the call is complete.  Apple introduced a confirmation box before placing the call in response to malicious apps making calls.

Comment: Some peace of code showcasing your solution would have been nice :)

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is a common Xamarin iOS async uri pattern and do not claim it as my own as it is used in a number OSS libraries:

```
public Task<bool> LaunchUriAsync(Uri uri)
{
    var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var sharedApp = UIApplication.SharedApplication;
    sharedApp.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var url = NSUrl.FromString(uri.ToString()) ?? new NSUrl(uri.Scheme, uri.Host, uri.LocalPath);
                var result = sharedApp.CanOpenUrl(url) && sharedApp.OpenUrl(url);
                completion.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                completion.SetException(exception);
            }
        });
    return completion.Task;
}
```

Examples:

```
await LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:demo@example.com"));
await LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("tel:555-555-5555"));
await LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
await LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("sms:555-555-5555"));
```

Comment: It looks good - I'll try it tomorrow. But if I remember correctly, OpenUrl returns immediately after dialing. So the task will be marked as completed before the call is actually over, won't it?

Comment: @Grisha Yes that is true. If you simply want to show an alert, the alert will immediately be displayed after the `OpenUrl` is called but the user should still see it when they return to the app from the phone call screen. If you wanted to do something more complex when the user returns from the phone call, then you would want to tap into either the `App.OnSleep()` event or even to some of the iOS specific events such as `AppDelegate.OnResignActivation()`. For some reason the `ContentPage.OnDisappearing()` event does not get called for me when attempting to make a phone call on iOS.

Comment: You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `telprompt:<phone-number>` scheme, this will return the user to your app after the call is finished.

Just one remark, this scheme is not officially support by Apple so they might remove it a some point.

There are only two ways to dial a number on iOS either `tel:<phone-number>` or `telprompt:<phone-number>`. There are no other ways.

Comment: telprompt is not good. It issues the prompt to the user, which I don't want. It's unofficial. And it doesn't help me with async/await pattern which I want to use - I still will have to use OpenUri, which is not awaitable.

Comment: In iOS 8.3(?) and above, `tel://` performs the same as `telprompt://`  I no longer use telprompt, just tel as after the call ends, the user is dropped back in the app that performed the openURL

Comment: @Grisha then you are out of luck, what you want is not possible.